# How do I cast a void pointer to a int[3]?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to call a 3rd party library and pass in an int[3] as a void * like this [works]:

```
int pattern[3] = {2,4,10};
if ( OSTaskCreate( BlinkLED,
        ( void * ) pattern,
        ( void * ) &BlinkTaskStack[USER_TASK_STK_SIZE],
        ( void * ) BlinkTaskStack,
        MAIN_PRIO - 1 ) != OS_NO_ERR )
{
    iprintf( "*** Error creating blink task\r\n" );
}
```

But now I need to parse a string to get the pattern array and I can't seem to get it right.

First I pass the string into the parser and get back the array:

```
int (&ParseBlinkOnCommand(char rxbuffer[3]))[3]
{
   // Code parses rxbuffer and creates the 3 ints needed

   int pattern[3] = {repeats, onTicks, offTicks};  
   return pattern;
}
```

Then I try to pass it to the OSTaskCreate just like I did before:

```
int pattern2[3] = ParseBlinkOnCommand(rxbuffer);                    
if ( OSTaskCreate( BlinkLED,
        ( void * ) pattern2,
        ( void * ) &BlinkTaskStack[USER_TASK_STK_SIZE],
        ( void * ) BlinkTaskStack,
        MAIN_PRIO - 1 ) != OS_NO_ERR )
{
    iprintf( "*** Error creating remote blink task\r\n" );
}
```

but I get the error 'array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer'.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: unrelated but you are returning a reference to ```int pattern[3]``` which is a local array - dont do that.

Comment: `int pattern[3] = {repeats, onTicks, offTicks};  return pattern;`  You are returning the address of a local variable.  This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `ParseBlinkOnCommand` returns reference to local object and so return dangling reference.

Second C-array are not copyable, so `int pattern2[3] = ParseBlinkOnCommand(rxbuffer);` should be `int (&pattern2)[3] = ParseBlinkOnCommand(rxbuffer);`.

but why not using `std::vector` or `std::array` (or custom structure) ?

```
std::vector<int> ParseBlinkOnCommand(const char (&rxbuffer)[3])
{
   // Code parses rxbuffer and creates the 3 ints needed

   return {repeats, onTicks, offTicks};  
}
```

And then

```
auto pattern2 = ParseBlinkOnCommand(rxbuffer);                    
if ( OSTaskCreate( BlinkLED,
                   pattern2.data(),
                   &BlinkTaskStack[USER_TASK_STK_SIZE],
                   BlinkTaskStack,
                   MAIN_PRIO - 1 ) != OS_NO_ERR )
{
    iprintf( "*** Error creating remote blink task\r\n" );
}
```

Comment: Going with a struct called patternType now (3 int fields) so pattern2 is now of type patternType. Since the 2nd parameter of OSTaskCreate must be a void* how do I pass the struct in? I'm thinking (void *) &pattern2... How do I cast it back to a patternType once inside the BlinkLED function, given the function signature 'void BlinkLED(void *pdata)? patternType myPattern = (patternType)pdata; isn't right...

Comment: Answer : `patternType pattern = *(patternType *)(pdata);`